# Failed to load resource. Server error 500

Tags: php, caching, path, directory

I have the following code which is used as an example for a caching class from the following [page](https://nielse63.github.io/php-image-cache/#installation)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Image Cache Test</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        img {
            max-width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $imagecache = new ImageCache();
        $imagecache->cached_image_directory = dirname(__FILE__) . '../';
        $cached_src_one = $imagecache->cache( 'background.jpg' );
        echo '<p>Original file size: ' . filesize($imagecache->image_src) . ' bytes</p>';
        echo '<p>PHPImageCach-ified file size: ' . filesize($imagecache->cached_filename) . ' bytes</p>';
        echo '<p>Total image size reduction: ' . (((filesize($imagecache->image_src) - filesize($imagecache->cached_filename)) / filesize($imagecache->image_src))*100) . '%</p>';
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $cached_src_one; ?>" alt="">
    <hr>
    <?php
        $imagecache->check_link_cached = false;
        $cached_src_two = $imagecache->cache( 'background.jpg' );
        echo '<p>Original file size: ' . filesize($imagecache->image_src) . ' bytes</p>';
        echo '<p>PHPImageCach-ified file size: ' . filesize($imagecache->cached_filename) . ' bytes</p>';
        echo '<p>Total image size reduction: ' . (((filesize($imagecache->image_src) - filesize($imagecache->cached_filename)) / filesize($imagecache->image_src))*100) . '%</p>';
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $cached_src_two; ?>" alt="">
    <hr>
    <?php
        $cached_src_two = $imagecache->cache( 'http://placehold.it/350x350' );
        echo 'Original file size: ' . filesize($imagecache->image_src) . ' bytes<br>';
        echo 'PHPImageCach-ified file size: ' . filesize($imagecache->cached_filename) . ' bytes<br>';
        echo 'Total image size reduction: ' . (((filesize($imagecache->image_src) - filesize($imagecache->cached_filename)) / filesize($imagecache->image_src))*100) . '%';
    ?>
    <p>Because the "compressed" file size is larger than the original, a local copy of the original file will be server instead.</p>
    <img src="<?php echo $cached_src_two; ?>" alt="">

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the mentioned error and not sure if it has to do something with the code. Everything is relative in terms of paths.

Comment: You have included the actual class somewhere, right?

Comment: `<?php require 'ImageCache.php'; ?>` at the top

Comment: Have you tried to enable PHP error messages to receive any useful info for debugging?

Comment: Will try a different workaround. How do I close topic?